# Log4J logs are not printed in IntelliJ console

Tags: java, intellij-idea, logging, log4j

I have problem with getting it work and I'm bit confused but I have one project when it works and there are only three dependencies in `pom.xml` without any configuration files.

So I copied these dependencies to my project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

but because nothing was displayed in console I added `log4j.properties` file under `src` folder
with following configuration:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I use it like this in my class:

```
I use it like this:

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import static org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger;

public class Main {
    protected static final Logger LOGGER = getLogger(Main.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        LOGGER.info("It's friday!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: how did you add log statements in your code?

Comment: make sure that the `log4j.properties` file should be under the folder `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Not the src folder but it should be src/main/resources Hint: with Spring Boot and Lombok logging is much easier.

Comment: I moved `log4j.properties` to `src/main/resources` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I added my usage of logger to first post

Comment: You are using a Log4j 1.x configuration file. Log4j 2.x uses as different configuration syntax and naming (config files are named `log4j2.*`). Cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#automatic-configuration)